# change keyboard shortcut by add-in for office?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I'm developing an excel add-in (office 2013).

I would like to overwrite an Excel keyboard shortcut.

For instance, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> must now **center the text in a cell**.

Where do I start? I can't find it in the interop documentation.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is no pure C# way to assign a shortcut to a command but I think I have just figured out a workaround.

In Excel, you can assign a shortcut to a macro. This obviously means you need to have a macro in your workbook. If you are working with interop you can **create a macro programmatically and assign a shortcut to it.**

Create an `addModule()` function which creates a standard coding module programmatically and writes code to it. Then use `Application.OnKey()` to assign a shortcut to that macro.

your `addModule()`

```
void addModule()
{
    VBProject vbProj = Globals.ThisWorkbook.VBProject as VBProject;
    VBComponent vbComp = 
                 vbProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
    vbComp.CodeModule.DeleteLines(1, vbComp.CodeModule.CountOfLines);

    string code = "Public Sub CentreText() \n" + 
                  "    activeCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter \n" +
                  "End Sub";

    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString(code);
}
```

The `code` string is a pure VBA macro which centres `activeCell`'s text horizontally.

Then anywhere in your executable code:

```
addModule();
Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
Workbook wb = ws.Parent as Workbook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = 
                         wb.Parent as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
app.OnKey("^e", "CentreText");
```